# Using VBA Loop to draw AutoCAD polyline

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I am trying to draw a polyline from the data of an Excel table, I have already achieved it manually, but I would like to know if there is a procedure with a loop that allows me to be more efficient in case of having more data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub polyline()

Dim vertexlist(0 To 8) As Double
Dim poli As Object

vertexlist(0) = Range("B11")
vertexlist(1) = Range("C11")
vertexlist(2) = Range("D11")

vertexlist(3) = Range("B12")
vertexlist(4) = Range("C12")
vertexlist(5) = Range("D12")

vertexlist(6) = Range("B13")
vertexlist(7) = Range("C13")
vertexlist(8) = Range("D13")

Set poli = AutoCAD.Application.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddPolyline(vertexlist)

poli.Closed = True

End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate the help. Greetings

[Excel File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2mAI2zjJVEV_v9EQd?e=Sgardc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. Not tested, I do not have AutoCad installed, but this should be the logic to be followed:

```
Sub polyline()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, vertexlist() As Double, firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, poli As Object, i As Long, k As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 firstRow = 11
 ReDim vertexlist((lastRow - firstRow + 1) * 3 - 1) '  -1 because the array is zero based
 For i = firstRow To lastRow
     vertexlist(k) = Range("B" & i).Value: k = k + 1
     vertexlist(k) = Range("C" & i).Value: k = k + 1
     vertexlist(k) = Range("D" & i).Value: k = k + 1
 Next i

 Set poli = AutoCAD.Application.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddPolyline(vertexlist)
 poli.closed = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have a kind error:
Subindex outside the interval.

Just from this line:
    vertexlist(k) = Range("B" & i).Value: k = k + 1

Also running the name of the variable in this other line:

ReDim vertexlist((lastRow - firstRow) * 3 - 1) '  -1 because the array is zero based

Comment: @DaniV Please, try the updated code. I tested it until filling the array. It was a logic mistake in re-dimensioning the array. If an error occurs during the iteration, this can happen only if the involved cells value cannot be converted to `Double` (strings, usually)...

Comment: Thank you very much, it served me a lot, I go little by little learning this new language. Best regards and an excellent day @FaneDuru.

Comment: @Glad I could help. Have a nice day, too!